# In mysql source code, there is 'DBUG_ENTER' function, now I use GDB to debug the server, and how can I open the 'DBUG_ENTER' switch to print the log?

Tags: mysql, open-source, innodb

For example, I will delete a row in one table which use the innodb engine, and how to output the debug info on console, like DBUG_ENTER.

Answer (score 1):

In short, as @geert3 stated, recompile with debug info and run the server with debug flag.

MySQL 5.6 in Ubuntu.

You need to obtain `mysqld` from sources and compile with debug info:
`cmake -DWITH_DEBUG=1`. You may want to add the option `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/your/test/dir` to do not destroy your MySQL original installation. Then, as usual, `make; make install;`.

Start the test server by hand. In Ubuntu: `export PATH=/your/test/dir/bin:$PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/test/dir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; sudo /your/test/dir/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --debug` (note the added **--debug** flag).

If you are not sure how it should be started in your particular platform, check how it is started by your installation's service manager. In Ubuntu, before setting the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables: `sudo service mysql start; ps -ef|fgrep mysqld`.

That's all. `DBUG_ENTER` don't send traces to console. They are sent to `/tmp/mysqld.trace`.

To stop your test server, in Ubuntu, find out the test server PID `sudo cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` and send it the TERM signal `kill <your-server-PID>`.

Answer (score 0):

These are macros that are expanded at compile time. To use them, you likely need to recompile MySQL in debug mode. In normal distributions they do nothing.

But why are you **debugging** the mysql server in the first place?

Comment: Learn transaction implementation of innodb, thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: do you have done something like that? and with to discuss with you sometimes.